# gamma glm to dgamma

Tags: generalized-linear-model, likelihood, gamma-distribution, weights

I am modelling the average claim amount (claim amount/number of claims), so i used a gamma glm with weights=number of claims, as:

```
> model<-glm(claimamount/numclaims ~ 1 + veh_age + zone + insured_age,
> family=Gamma(link = "log"), weights = numclaims)
```

After this i want to find the log likelihood at each observation, but glm only return the sum, for instances:

```
> logLik(model) 
>'log Lik.' -70665.26
```

**How can i get the loglikelihood for each observation?**

I tried to do:

```
> x<-claimamount/numclaims 
> m<-model.matrix(model)       # covariates
> mu<-as.vector(exp(m%*%coef(model)))    #mean
> delta<-summary(model)$dispersion     # dispersion parameter
> ll<-log(dgamma(x,1/delta,1/(delta*mu)))
```

But when i sum all the loglikelihoods(to check if it is ok), i don't get the same value as in `logLik(model)`.

My question is: what am i doing wrong? is it because i used weights in glm and i also have to use the weights in dgamma?

Comment: You will need to show us the details of what you're doing if you would like us to identify what is going wrong.  If the call to `dgamma` literally is what you have computed, then evidently you need to take its logarithm using the `log=TRUE` argument.

Comment: @whuber i hope that it is more understandable now

Comment: It is, thank you.  Are you sure you have the arguments to `dgamma` correct?

Comment: @whuber it is correct when there is no weights, according to the glm/gamma parameterization... but i am not sure if it is the same when we have weights, it is one of my questions

Answer (score 1):

The problem, as you noticed yourself, is that you use weights for your model, while you are not using them in your by-hand calculations. If you check the [source of `logLik.glm`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/logLik.R#L54), you'll see that it uses AIC to calculate back the log likelihood:

```r
p <- object$rank
## allow for estimated dispersion
if(fam %in% c("gaussian", "Gamma", "inverse.gaussian")) p <- p + 1
val <- p - object$aic / 2
```

Now compare the [`Gamma` source](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/af7f52f70101960861e5d995d3a4bec010bc89e6/src/library/stats/R/family.R#L467) to check how AIC is calculated:

```r
dev.resids <- function(y, mu, wt)
    -2 * wt * (log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) - (y - mu)/mu)
aic <- function(y, n, mu, wt, dev){
n <- sum(wt)
disp <- dev/n
-2*sum(dgamma(y, 1/disp, scale=mu*disp, log=TRUE)*wt) + 2
```

it uses *weighted* deviance to calculate it. In fact, for weighted data we use weighted likelihood (see [example here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/202752/how-do-you-fit-a-poisson-distribution-to-table-data/202754#202754))