# Why aren't the outputs of the softmax and logistic function the same in this example?

Tags: logistic, softmax

I am trying to understand the equivalence between the logistic function and the softmax function, when k = 2. My understanding is that the following code should output the same values. Where is my mistake?

```
def sigmoid(x):
    x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float)
    x = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
    return x

def softmax(x):
    x = np.asarray(x)
    x = np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))
    return x

x = .5
b1 = 1
b2 = -1
sigmoid(x*b1), sigmoid(x*b2), softmax([x*(b1-b2), x*(b2-b2)])
---
Output> 0.6224593312018546, 0.3775406687981454, array([0.73105858, 0.26894142])
```

Is it because I am assuming that the softmax optimization would find the same betas?

Comment: Also: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/233658/softmax-vs-sigmoid-function-in-logistic-classifier/254071#254071

Comment: I see no reason why these two functions should return the same values, because they appear to use different denominators.  Could you explain why you think they are equivalent?

Comment: @whuber The two links above show why the two are theoretically linked, and the answer below shows what is the relationship between the coefficients that I was missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assumption for two class logistic regression and softmax to have the same values is the follows

**beta ( logistic regression ) = -(beta1 - beta2)**

Following code gives the matching numbers

```
    def sigmoid1(x):
        x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float)
        x = 1 / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return x

    def sigmoid0(x):
        x = np.asarray(x, dtype=np.float)
        x = np.exp(-x) / (1 + np.exp(-x))
        return x

    def softmax(x):
        x = np.asarray(x)
        x = np.exp(x)/np.sum(np.exp(x))
        return x

    x = .5
    b = -2
    b1 = 1
    b2 = -1
    sigmoid0(x*b), sigmoid1(x*b), softmax([x*b1, x*b2])

(0.7310585786300049, 0.2689414213699951, array([0.73105858, 0.26894142]))
```