# Sigmoid equivalent to Softmax exercise 2

Tags: reinforcement-learning, softmax, sigmoid-curve

This question is not the same as [this one](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/561173/sigmoid-equivalent-to-softmax-exercise/561175#561175) I asked previously. In the previous question I asked to prove that the sigmoid and softmax are equivalent. I found a solution [here](https://github.com/iamhectorotero/rlai-exercises/blob/master/Chapter%202/Exercise%202.7.md), but I think it's not correct. Here is the exercise that I'm trying to do:

[image]

And here is how they prove it:

[image]

However it seems incorrect because I don't think we can set $H_t(b)\leftarrow H_t(b)-H_t(b)=0$ and then consequently set $H_t(a)\leftarrow H_t(a)-H_t(b)=H_t(a)$ because it does change the probability. I mean let $H_t(a)=2$ and then left $H_t(b)=1$ and then $H_t(b)\leftarrow 0$. It's not true that (softmax) $P(A_t=a)=\frac{e^2}{e^2+e^1}=\frac{e^2}{e^2+e^0}$

So what is actually the correct way to do it?

Comment: The question is nearly the same as your previous one, so I'm marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After slightly simplifying the notation, by the properties of the [exponential function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_function):

$$
\frac{e^{a-b}}{e^{a-b} + e^{b-b}} = \frac{e^a e^{-b}}{e^a e^{-b} + e^b e^{-b}} = \frac{e^a}{e^a + e^b}
$$

[Here you can double check](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28e%5E%7Ba-b%7D%29%20%2F%20%28e%5E%7Ba-b%7D%20%2B%20e%5E%7Bb-b%7D%29).

Using your example,

```r
> exp(2)/(exp(2) + exp(1))
[1] 0.7310586
> exp(2-1)/(exp(2-1) + exp(1-1))
[1] 0.7310586
```

Notice that you forgot to update the value of $H_t(a)$.

Comment: Thank you. But I didn't forget, I think they forgot, and that was the point of my question - to ask whether their solution is incorrect

Comment: They didn't forget anything.

Comment: I think they forgot to update $H_t(a)$. They write $H_t(a)\leftarrow H_t(a)-0=H_t(a)$. Your example shows the updated version where $H_t(a)-1 \neq H_t(a)$

Comment: is my last comment incorrect? In case it's correct, could you please reopen the question or edit your answer?

Comment: $H_t(a) - H_t(b)$ not $H_t(a) - 0$

Comment: But they write $H_t(a) \leftarrow H_t(a)-H_t(b)=H_t(a)$? Which clearly implies $H_t(b)=0$? And they do that because before they show that $H_t(b)\leftarrow H_t(b)-H_t(b)=0$.

Comment: @SlimShady but those are not operations that are done sequentially. It also wouldn't make any sense to subtract zero.

Comment: They are not done sequentially, I know - that's why i'm confused how exactly $H_t(a)\leftarrow H_t(a)$?

Comment: $H_t(b)' \leftarrow H_t(b) - H_t(b)$ and $H_t(a)' \leftarrow H_t(a) - H_t(b)$

Comment: Okay, but then why in the end they write $P(A=a) = \frac{e^{H_t(a)}}{e^{H_t(a)}+1}$ instead of $\frac{e^{H_t(a)-H_t(b)}}{e^{H_t(a)-H_t(b)}+1}$?

Comment: @SlimShady because they don't distinguish in the notation the old vs new values and assume the reader would understand this from the context.

Comment: You are correct, I'm blind.. I was fixated on the fact that they did it sequentially.. thank you very much for explaining