# Why does the BERT NSP head linear layer have two outputs?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, natural-language

Here's [the code](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L491) in question:

```
class BertOnlyNSPHead(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, config):
        super().__init__()
        self.seq_relationship = nn.Linear(config.hidden_size, 2)

    def forward(self, pooled_output):
        seq_relationship_score = self.seq_relationship(pooled_output)
        return seq_relationship_score
```

I think it was just ranking how likely one sentence would follow another? Wouldn't it be one score?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can see from [these two lines](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/0866669e751bef636fa693b704a28c1fea9a17f3/src/transformers/modeling_bert.py#L1159-L1160) that it's cross entropy loss and it's a score.

```
loss_fct = CrossEntropyLoss()
loss = loss_fct(logits.view(-1, self.num_labels), labels.view(-1))
```

The NSP is a binarized next sentence prediction task, and you may need to refer to this question: [Is binary logistic regression a special case of multinomial logistic regression when the outcome has 2 levels?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/87248/103153).

When the size of the label for sequence prediction is 1, it is doing regression using mean square error.